# State-operator correspondence in 2D CFT

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, conformal-field-theory, quantum-states

In CFT we can express a state in terms of it's operator by
$$
|\phi\rangle=\lim_{z,\bar{z}\rightarrow 0} \phi(z,\bar{z}) |0\rangle
$$

Now in 2D we can expand our field in terms of $\phi_n$ as
$$
\phi(z) = \sum_n\phi_nz^{-n-h}
$$
How can I find the state corresponding to the field after I act on the field with an operator?

Comment: Have you computed $\lim_{z\to 0} \phi(z) | 0\rangle$?

Comment: @user1504 No, I don't quite see how we can compute that.

Comment: @user1504 okay so calculating that gives $|\phi\rangle = \phi_{-h}|0\rangle$ because of the limit. But what about the state that corresponds to an operator which we act another operator on ?